# ORA-00904: "TIMESTAMP": invalid identifier on perl script

Tags: oracle, perl

```
DBI->connect using 'old-style' syntax is deprecated and will be an error in future 
versions at /home/dbadmin/perl/adm_audit_mhs line 43
Can't prepare SQL statement: ORA-00904: "TIMESTAMP": invalid identifier (DBD ERROR: 
error possibly near <*> indicator at char 281 in 
   'SELECT OS_USERNAME, USERNAME, TERMINAL, TIMESTAMP, 
           SQL_TEX,0,'Successful','Failed') RETURNCODE
    FROM unified_audit_trail
    WHERE action IN (43,51,53)
      AND <*>timestamp between Trunc(SYSDATE-1) AND Trunc(SYSDATE)')
```

Please help I'm getting this error while running a perl script to pull information from  unified_audit_trail view. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As the error indicates, there is no `timestamp` column in [`unified_audit_trail`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-B7CE1C02-2FD4-47D6-80AA-CF74A60CDD1D.htm#REFRN29162).  There is an `event_timestamp` column which is what I'm guessing you meant to reference.